# Find the union and intersection of a collection of maps?

Tags: java, set

I have a collection of Maps `maps` and I want a set with all the keys amongst the maps (the union), a set with all the keys common to all the maps (the intersection), and a set with all the keys that are only in some sets but not all (the disjunctive union).

My questions are: is there a way to get the disjunctive union "diff" other than just taking the compliment of "same", i.e. is there any way it be done within the for loop in parallel with "all" and "same", instead of after those two sets are created? Second, must I get an element of the collection of maps to initialize "same" with? Or can it be built in the for loop with some other function than "retainAll" and be initialized empty?

Basically what, if any, is an alternative logic to the approach given below?

```java
Set<String> same = new HashSet<>(maps.get(0).keySet());
Set<String> diff = new HashSet<>();
Set<String> all = new HashSet<>();

for(Map map : maps) {
    all.addAll(map.keySet());
    same.retainAll(map.keySet());
}
diff.addAll(all);
diff.removeAll(same);
```

Comment: Looks reasonable to me. Is there a problem with your code?

Comment: That looks like the best approach.

Comment: If the code works, the question might be more on-topic  at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I suggest re-wording the first sentence of your second paragraph. Some folks here over-react to the phrase "best way", confusing that with the prohibition here on overly-opinionated open-ended questions.

Comment: I have reworded my second paragraph to be clearer as to what exactly I would like to know. I am just doubtful that the approach given here is the simplest way to go about it.

Comment: Off-topic side note: For the intersection I would perhaps sort the maps by size and start intersecting from the smallest one(s).

Answer (score 1):

if by elegant you mean stream based, maybe try with this:

1. output = a TreeMap with keys and their counts.
2. union = the map keyset
3. intersection = all entries with value = maps.size()
4. different = all entries with value < maps.size()

```
    List<Map<String, String>> maps = new ArrayList<>();
    // Fill maps and after:
    Integer mapCount = maps.size();
    Map<String, Integer> output = maps.stream().flatMap(m -> m.keySet().stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e, e -> 1, (a, b) -> a + 1, TreeMap::new));
    // Union
    Collection<String> union = output.keySet();
    // Intersection value = mapCount
    Collection<String> intersection = output.entrySet().stream().filter(e -> mapCount.equals(e.getValue()))
        .map(e -> e.getKey()).collect(Collectors.toList());
    // Difference value != mapCount
    Collection<String> different = output.entrySet().stream().filter(e -> !mapCount.equals(e.getValue()))
        .map(e -> e.getKey()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

here is a sample run:

```
MapSample.main()
MapSample.mapper()
# # # Map 01:
{p={}, q={}, g={}, h={}, y={}, z={}, m={}, o={}}
# # # Map 02:
{b={}, d={}, f={}, g={}, h={}, k={}, l={}, m={}, o={}, p={}, q={}, r={}, s={}, t={}, u={}, v={}, y={}, z={}}
# # # Map 03:
{b={}, c={}, d={}, e={}, h={}, i={}, k={}, n={}, r={}, s={}, t={}, u={}, v={}, w={}}
{b=2, c=1, d=2, e=1, f=1, g=2, h=3, i=1, k=2, l=1, m=2, n=1, o=2, p=2, q=2, r=2, s=2, t=2, u=2, v=2, w=1, y=2, z=2}
[b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, y, z]
[h]
[b, c, d, e, f, g, i, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, y, z]
```

**Update:**
this problem is very interesting to me, so I coded a generic function to compute the union, intersection and differences (handles nulls):

```
  private static <K, V> Collection<Collection<K>> processMaps(Collection<Map<K, V>> maps) {
    Collection<Map<K, V>> mapCollection = Optional.ofNullable(maps).orElseGet(Collections::emptyList);
    Map<K, Integer> keyCount = mapCollection.stream()
        .map(e -> Optional.ofNullable(e).orElseGet(Collections::emptyMap))
        .flatMap(m -> m.keySet().stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e, e -> 1, (a, b) -> a + 1, TreeMap::new));
    Map<Boolean, List<Entry<K, Integer>>> partitioned = keyCount.entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(e -> e.getValue() == mapCollection.size()));
    Collection<Collection<K>> result = new ArrayList<>();
    // union
    result.add(keyCount.keySet());
    // intersection
    result.add(partitioned.get(true).stream().map(e -> e.getKey()).collect(Collectors.toList()));
    // differences
    result.add(partitioned.get(false).stream().map(e -> e.getKey()).collect(Collectors.toList()));
    return result;
  }
```

this is the result of a test run, values in maps are ignored, this only processes the keys:

```
MapSample02.main()
MapSample02.computeTestData()
maps:4
map
{a=2, c=2, d=5, e=2, f=1, h=2, i=3, k=1, l=2, m=4, n=2, o=2, p=1, q=4, r=2, s=2, t=4, u=4, v=3, x=3, y=1, z=2}
map
{a=2, c=3, d=1, f=2, g=2, j=1, l=1, m=1, n=1, o=2, p=3, u=1, v=3, w=2, x=3, y=2}
map
{a=1, b=1, c=1, d=1, e=1, f=1, g=3, h=1, i=1, k=1, n=3, o=1, p=2, q=3, r=1, s=1, t=3, u=2, v=2, w=2, x=1, y=1}
map
{a=4, c=4, d=4, e=1, f=7, g=4, h=3, i=2, j=4, k=2, l=3, n=2, o=2, p=6, q=1, r=2, s=1, v=1, w=3, x=3, y=3, z=2}
union, intersection, differences:
[[a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z], [a, c, d, f, n, o, p, v, x, y], [b, e, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, q, r, s, t, u, w, z]]
```

Comment: if you return  a Collection<Object> instead you can return: ```result.add(partitioned.get(false));``` as the third result and you will know how many maps contain each key.